# MariaDB to DynamoDB migration how to transform dates to specific format?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-dms

Currently investigating migration of data from mariadb to dynamodb and encountared a question

in MariaDB we have fields like:

```
modified - DATETIME
created  - DATETIME
```

And the date is stored as:

```
2023-10-20 08:59:55
```

But, when trying to migrate data to DynamoDB the date is written in ISO 8601 format. So the date is stored as so:

```
2023-10-20T08:59:55Z
```

My question is:
Is it possible to create a DMS(data migration service) rule that transforms in the format without T and Z? Like in DynamoDB?

Currently the data migration rule for DMS is done like so:

```
{
    "mapping-parameters": {
        "attribute-mappings": [
            {
                "target-attribute-name": "modified",
                "attribute-type": "scalar",
                "attribute-sub-type": "string",
                "value": "${modified}"
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Would appreciate any info on the topic. Thanks!